# SSIS Package is only importing a small number of rows from large excel worksheet

Tags: sql, ssis

I am working with an SSIS package that was built for us to import an excel sheet into a database.  Usually, if there are any issues the package will error out and we have to figure out where the error is in our data set.  Today I encountered a new issue, where the package appears to be completing successfully, but it is only importing about 200 rows out of 9000.  I have looked at the last rows that were imported and I don't see anything unique on those rows in our excel file.  I was curious if anyone has seen this issue and might have some suggestions for things I can check in the excel file that might be impacting the SSIS package.

Again normally the SSIS package is very quick to error out, so it is odd that we are seeing it say it is successful when it is only importing a fraction of the total rows.

Comment: If you open the sheet and select a field in the first row and press ctrl + shift + 8  (aka ctrl + *) what did it select?

Comment: Does it select the same region as is being imported?

Comment: Check for blank rows in the data

Comment: We actually were able to figure it out.  There was not really anything on my end.  It turns out there was an issue with the way the Stored Procedure was written to import the data.  Because I didn't have a type of data in the first ~150 rows, when the SSIS encountered the new data  type (in an existing column) it essentially errored out.  I was able to sort the data to ensure all my data types were at the top and then it worked without any issues.